# nodemon + pm2 start "filename", zsh: command not found: pm2. always same error

Tags: node.js, zsh, pm2, nodemon

I'm testing a file but when I tried to run pm2 always get the same error, I follow two instruction here Stackoverflow,

```
npm config get prefix 
`Then this will be return some thing like this:`

/Users/your_user/npm-global
`Copy this path, and add the /bin in the end -> /Users/your_user/npm-global/bin. Then we will export this path into the bash configs.`

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/your_user/npm-global/bin
```

and it ran perfecly  but when I close the file come back the same error `zsh: command not found: pm2.` next day I found another way  to run the command because the previus one does not work twice, so I run this one `export PATH=$PATH:$(npm config get prefix)/bin` everything was fine. I close the file and again, `zsh: command not found: pm2`. now I can not run pm2. I just starting leaning nodejs so I don’t know what is happening.

this is my path:

```
➜  node-fundamentals git:(main) ✗ npm config get prefix                                
/usr/local/Cellar/node/18.11.0
➜  node-fundamentals git:(main) ✗ pm2 start monothread.js
zsh: command not found: pm2
```

please can someone help and understand why after I ran the comand above it giving the same error. thank you.

please can someone help and understand why after I ran the comand above it giving the same error. thank you.

what I should do to run pm2 properly, thank you.

Comment: Add your `export ...` command at the end of your .zshrc in your home directory. Therefore your `PATH` var will be adopted every time your users accounts starts a new zsh session.